VBA Type missmatch in For Each loop
My code gives my type missmatch.
I dont know why, beacuse cf is type FormatCondition
Sub ClearBottomBorderConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cf As FormatCondition
    
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    
    For Each cf In ws.Cells.FormatConditions
        
        If cf.Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
            
            cf.Delete
        End If
    Next cf
End Sub


For me the code works. On which line do you get the error?

@Ike line Next cf

What happens when you remove cf from the next line (it is not necessary). What kind of format conditions are applied to the sheet?

Just saw the deleted post: at which i do you get the error? Maybe this is a special format condition ...


Believe or not, the type of cf is UniqueValues instead of FormatCondition.

Sub ClearBottomBorderConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cf  As Variant ' UniqueValues
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cf In ws.Cells.FormatConditions
        Debug.Print TypeName(cf) ' validate data type
        If cf.Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
            cf.Delete
        End If
    Next cf
End Sub

Microsoft documentation:

UniqueValues object (Excel)

